# Laravel specify different name from `.env` or make ingore `.env` in order not to conflict with docker and docker-compose

Tags: laravel, docker, docker-compose

Because I use `docker` and `docker-compose` instead of `Homestead` and any `Vargrant`-based solution for development, I want to avoid conflict with laravel on the use of `.env` file. Therefore, I want for the laravel not to look for this file, instead fetch the required settings data from environmental variables.

So how I can specify, configure the laravel **NOT** to look for `.env` file? If that is not possible how I can change the name of the file to search for environmental variables and settings?

The `docker-compose.yml` is located on the project's root folder.

My `docker-compose.yml` is the:

```
version: '3.1'
services:
  develop:
    image: ddesyllas/php-dev:${TAG}
    volumes:
      - ".:/var/www/html"
    links: 
      - memcache
    environment:
      DB_CONNECTION: postgresql
      DB_HOST : postgresql
      DB_PORT : 5432
      DB_DATABASE: ${DOCKER_POSTGRES_DB}
      DB_USERNAME: ${DOCKER_POSTGRES_USER}
      DB_PASSWORD: ${DOCKER_POSTGRES_PASSWORD}

  nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    ports:
      - 7880:7880
    links:
      - "develop:develop"
    volumes:
      - ".:/var/www/html"
      - "./docker/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro"


  postgresql:
    image: postgres:alpine
    volumes:
      - './docker/misc_volumes/postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql/data'
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: ${DOCKER_POSTGRES_USER}
      POSTGRES_DB: ${DOCKER_POSTGRES_DB}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${DOCKER_POSTGRES_PASSWORD}

  memcache:
    image: memcached:alpine
```

Therefore there's the need for global settings in an aoproach use once-apply globally approach. For example I do not want my laravel application to have access into the `${TAG}` enviromental variable at all.

Comment: I do not want per-container variables I want the whole `docker-compose.yml` to use the .env as variable provider and not the laravel. As you can see I use the `docker-compose.yml` to pass the required settings.

Comment: I mean the `laravel` not to use/read the `.env` at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `docker-compose.yml` you can specify the `env_file` different then `.env` like:

```
version: "3.1"
services:
  webserver:
    image: nginx:alpine
    restart: always
    container_name: laravel-webserver
    working_dir: /application
    env_file:
      - .env_docker
    networks: 
      - intranet

networks:
  intranet:
    external: false
```

Here the `docker-compose.yml` will use `.env_docker` instead of `.env`

**Edited:**

If you would like to use the different file for the laravel `.env` then you can change the `volumns` section to specify that Like:

```
volumes:
      - ".:/var/www/html"
      - "./docker/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro"
      - "/<path to your different env file>:/var/www/html/.env"
```

Comment: In other wards specify asny enviromental variable in nginx.conf and pass them via fastcgi right?

Comment: So you say to use a volume asnd mount it into a different path in order for the laravel to look a different .env right?

Comment: Yes.. you can do like that... you can choose another file then .env from src and it would be renamed in as .env in container.

Comment: Check the `Edited` section for the details.

Comment: Also in order to avoid any further conflict the file `.env` should be placed into `.dockerignore` as well.